# How to pass link to react ant design model "Confirm/yes/ok " click button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here my problem is when I click the button to show this model. I need to pass the link when I click the model button "ok" this link go to..how do I do?

[image]

Here is my button code:

```
   <Button onClick={this.showConfirm} style={{ color: '#036cd2',verticalAlign:'middle', borderColor: '#ffffff', backgroundColor: '#ffffff', border: 0, visibility: this.props.colBtn,marginRight:5 }}  shape={'circle'}><Icon type="poweroff" /></Button>
```

this my model function:

```
  showConfirm=() =>{
      confirm({
        title: 'Do You Want to Logout...?',

        onOk() {
          console.log('Ok');
        },
        onCancel() {
          console.log('Cancel');
        },
      });
    }
```

Here is my logout function:

```
 logout(){
        var accessToken =localStorage.getItem('access_token');
        if(!accessToken){
            axios.post(`${Config.serverUrl}/api/Employes/logout?access_token=${accessToken}`, null).then((response) =>{
                localStorage.clear();
            });
        }else {
            message.error('access token required ');
        }

    }
```

this coding working without a model. I need(with model) when I click "ok" button link and logout function must work.

```
  { <Link  to="/user-login"  ><Button onClick={this.logout} style={{ color: '#036cd2',verticalAlign:'middle', borderColor: '#ffffff', backgroundColor: '#ffffff', border: 0, visibility: this.props.colBtn,marginRight:5 }}  shape={'circle'}><Icon type="poweroff" /></Button></Link> }
```

Comment: @Luca how do sir?

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to add a `Link` there. You can simply call your `logout()` inside `onOk`.

```
showConfirm=() =>{
      confirm({
        title: 'Do You Want to Logout...?',

        onOk() {
          logout();
        },
        onCancel() {
          console.log('Cancel');
        },
      });
    }
```

Comment: sirnot working ... Here does not give link("/user-login")?

Comment: Sorry, didnt get you. You said, `this coding working without a model.`?

Comment: @ Rohith Murali sir ..i need with model  this mean when i click the model 'ok' button these function must work

Comment: `onOk()` get called when you click ok, so it is enough to call the logout function inside the `onOk` as i mentioned in the answer.

Comment: when i click the "ok' button nothing happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174435/discussion-between-rohith-murali-and-gnanaseelan).

Comment: can't pass the link to ok button?

Comment: This is a confirmation dialog, if you want to have a custom button, you will have to create a usual dialog and customise the buttons as per your need